# Give Permissions to the Excel WebPart

Tags: 2013, web-part, permissions, excel

I created a new webpart page with ExcelWebRenderer. I want to give edit permission to a group for the excel page. Other persons have read only permission for this excel page.

I created a group and I gave full control permission to the group. And other members have read permissions only. But everyone can open read only mode the excel.

How can I give permission for the excel? Where can edit properties the excel webpart? 
Not: I'm using Sharepoint Designer 2013.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you wanna hide the webpart for everyone but one group of users, you can edit the page and edit the Excel webpart and set the audience to a specific SharePoint group. Doing it this way, it will only be visible to the specif group of users.

Comment: I dont want hide the webpart for everyone. I want to they can see but can't edit. one group can edit. @user19952